# Searching for xml to jekyll converter

Tags: xml, wordpress, jekyll

I'm struggling to find a good xml to jekyll importer. I have a Wordpress (WP) site,  but the WP guide did not work for me, so I have exported it to xml.
I would be grateful for a nudge in the right direction.

Comment: Welcome to SO! I tried to guess what you mean, but there is information missing. Please edit your question according to the [guidelines](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Answer (score 0):

I'm not aware of an out-of-the-box "WP-XML to Jekyll converter". If You know XML/XSLT and some bash scripting, You could export WP to XML and use an XSLT processor like Saxon transforming the WP-XML to HTML. If you don't know XML/XSLT, I would not recommend this approach, unless You want to spend weeks learning the ins and outs of XML/XSLT/XPATH/X....

Answer (score 0):

the docs on jekyll have two ways:
one through xml meant for wordpress**.com** sites

- see https://import.jekyllrb.com/docs/wordpressdotcom/

one through the database meant for wordpress sites

- see https://import.jekyllrb.com/docs/wordpress/

now, i don’t really know if you can use that wordpress.com exporter for a custom install of wordpress, because i *just* tried to, and it just pooped out an empty assets folder... :(